# Simple Rails Blog Application with newsletter functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, newsletter

I'm looking for a simple rails blog webapp with newsletter functionality.

As the title says, I'm looking for something simple that can be extensible via plugins later.

Please avoid the answers like "roll your own, it's easy". We really don't have time to do it right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try it
http://rubygems.org/gems/mynewsletterbuilder

A simple xml restful newsletter application

Comment: Thx, I'll look at it. But I'll keep looking for a blog with newsletter already feature already included before messing with a normal blog and add the newsletter myself